# How does GitHub handle a moving Pull Request?

Tags: git, github

I was reading this article from Atlassian, about BitBucket:
https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/a-better-pull-request
on how they create a temporary merge commit, to be able to show the true modified files when there are new commits on "master", in their examples.

But then they link to show the diff on how it looks on GitHub, and I find it very hard to believe, that PR's on GitHub dont show these changes someone already pushed into Master!

This smells very much like a marketing trick from Atlassian to me, can someone who uses GitHub frequently here, how is this issue being addressed? This is a pretty basic feature/requirement, to display updated diff on a pull request...

Comment: Atlassian isn’t lying. GitHub pull requests show a diff against their base, and to confirm that you can… try it.

Comment: That does not make sense, why would then so many organizations use GitHub, if the PR diff view is so unreliable? In other words, how do people workaround the problem they demonstrated, in github? How can you do a review for pull request on github, knowing it can be a waste of time?

Comment: Unreliable? It’s never bothered me. Easy enough to add a merge commit besides, and branch protection to require a branch to be up to date before merging.

Comment: @Carmageddon The "problem" here is with Git itself, not necessarily services like GitHub. The article you link explains it very well and markets BitBucket's solution. GitHub's solution is to warn you that your PR branch is behind master. When you merge master into your PR branch, then you will see the entire diff between both branches.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice then that sounds like the answer to this, along with branch protection like `@Ry-` mentioned. If someone can cook that into a singular answer, I can accept that as the answer.